# Particular Page on Voyager shows not found

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Hello everyone please I'm having a challenge with my laravel voyager admin panel. I updated my composer package because I upgraded my php version. After doing that all my pages on laravel voyager are woking except `/admin/products`  I've tried all my best to solve the problem by running the following commands

```
php artisan optimize
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan key:generate
```

Just to mention I've tried every command that clears cache in laravel yet the page still returns 404 not found. I've also done `php artisan route:list` to check if the route exists and that route is also found among the list. Please I seriously need help on this I'll appreciate any effort made to help me with this. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please add your `route:list` output to the question.

Comment: As text, please, and the whole list; that appears to be just a partial section.